# Loading trained svm in java

Tags: opencv

I can't figure out how to load a trained .yml file in java. I have trained the file in c++ and it works fine there.

```
HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();
//In c++ it is svm = StatModel::load<SVM>( "detector.yml" ); but in java SVM has no load method, only create();
SVM svm = SVM.create();
Mat model = svm.getSupportVectors();
hog.setSVMDetector(model);
hog.detectMultiScale(image,detections,foundWeights);
```

Also found `Ptr<SVM> svm = Algorithm::read<SVM>(fn);` which reads a file FileNode but it's protected.

The `HOGDescriptor` should also have read and load methods according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a957f55d36ba2f1a2ae47883c11f4b730) but there are'nt any of them available in java.

Comment: I thought it did have a [load](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/ml/CvStatModel.html#load(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: that's a [bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4279) in the 3.0 wrappers

Comment: @GPPK OpenCV 3.0 does not have CvStatModel class it has been changed to StatModel.

Comment: @berak thanks, I did not find from there :)

Comment: i made a quick test, and the HOGDescriptor.load() and save() methods **do work**

Comment: With opencv 3.0? For me it does not even offer the possibility to use load() method.

Comment: Oh okay now I shee what you mean. This HOGDescriptor.load() is not capable to read .yml file. It is read as zero size `Mat [ 0*1*CV_32FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x4cc750, dataAddr=0x0 ]`

Comment: @berak HOGDescriptor cannot load a .yml.
Is there any way (even hacky ones work) to load a yml file in the StatModel? 
PS. The Java wrappers are autogenerated, and I would like to stick to OpenCV 3+ since all methods are optimized to run on gpgpus using OpenCL.